# How to export Sonar violations for a given version?

Tags: export, sonarqube

I have a Sonar server used to daily analyse my code. I can compare last analysis with other, but I would like to be able to export the results of a previous analysis, for example one which I tagged as a special version. Is this possible, and how? Alternatively, is it possible to browse violations for a given version?

Thanks

Comment: Given the first answers, I realise my wish it to be able to select a previous version in sonar and export the list of violations at that time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Time Machine web service API should answer your needs: http://docs.codehaus.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=229743292

Comment: Thanks David. This looks interesting, but doesn't seem to be able to report the violations list. However I'm afraid there's no solution as the "violations" web service does not have any "fromDateTime" parameter

Comment: Indeed, it's not currently possible for violations. But will be in a week or so when SonarQube 3.6 is released. See Issues: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Issues and Issues web service: http://docs.codehaus.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=231080558

Comment: Thanks David, this is great news! Roll on the release!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the reporting plugins under

http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Plugin+Library

There is a PDF plugin and one for Timeline. I am sure one of them will suffice for your requirement.

Comment: Thanks, but: I already investigated these plugins, and: 1) PDF Plugin requires to run analysis with maven (which I can't), and 2) Timeline is only a graphical convenience for few stats, not an exhaustive list of violations

Comment: Can you tell me why you cannot run the plugin using maven. Are you using ant as build tool?

Comment: Yes exactly, and I'd go for Maven if it were up to me; moreover there I have multiple ant build files with classpath variable wich I reuse for sonar findbugs plugin. It would be annoying to have to duplicate it.